# Determining the type of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a mystery object in Javascript - please could someone tell me how to initialise a similar object?

Background: I've inherited some code that gets passed a `params` object from Flash. I want to 'fake' the same call, which requires manually constructing the same object. But I can't work out how to take it, because I don't know what type of object it is. (It's not the *content* that's the problem: it's *how* to initialise the object.)

Please could someone tell me whether the `params` object following is an array, a list, a hash or something else - or at least how I can work it out for myself, given that there is no `typeof` in JavaScript?

```
function doSomething(params) {
    var txt;
    for (p in params) {
       txt = txt + "param:" + p + ", " + params[p] + "\n";
    }
    return txt;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `given that there is no typeof in JavaScript?` sez who? :D Try `alert(typeof params);`

Comment: JavaScript does actually have `typeof` - however, it returns `'object'` for objects and arrays. JavaScript does _not_ have a separate list type.

Comment: First of all, use console.log(params) to examine that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will alert the type of 'params'.

```
function doSomething(params) {
    alert("Type of params variable: " + typeof params);
    var txt = '', p;
    for (p in params) {
       txt += "param:" + p + ", " + params[p] + "\n";
    }
    return txt;
}
```

If you just want to intercept the variable, and pass the param to the original function, try this:

```
window.originalFunction = doSomething;
window.doSomething = function(param1){
   // do something with param1
   return window.originalFunction(param1);
};
```

To check whether `params` is an array or not, try:

```
alert(params instanceof Array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a hash. In your example, `p` is the property name and `params[p]` accesses the value of that named property.

And, as usual, Pekka is right. There most definitely *is* a "typeof" operator in Javascript. I don't know where you got the idea that there isn't.

Comment: thanks. To be fair though, Javascript's `typeof` doesn't distinguish between arrays and objects, which I didn't know until now.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, `params` looks like a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There are no lists, hashes, dictionaries (etc.) in JavaScript. There are only objects and arrays (and arrays are a type of object).

Given that the code uses `for... in`, it looks like it would be an Object. That is, a container with named members. Beyond that, it depends on how the object was initialized.

If you would like to make a copy of the object, try using its prototype:

```
var copy = {};
copy.prototype = params
```